# make pip install -e include test helper modules

Tags: python, pip, python-3.9

I have a django app with the standard structure

```
Project
   - src
   - tests
      - helpers
```

I'm running a virtual environment and inside of it have done a pip install -e on my project to get all the editable magic.

However I now have some utility functions defined in the tests/helpers module to make it easier to quickly set up dummy values in my db. Ideally I'd like this to also be on my pythonpath whenever I run "migrate.py shell" so it's easy to import and use the utilities any time I want to tweak my dummy db stuff based off of my current development needs.  Unfortunately right now only project/src, not project/tests, is actually in the PYTHONPATH.

Is there a clean way to tell it to also include my test methods when I'm in dev mode?  by clean I mean ideally using pip install magic, or I suppose django magic, instead of directly hacking my PYTHONPATH.  others will be installing a dev mode version of our project so they can test their plugins with it and I want the steps to make these helper modules available to use to be as straight forward as possible.

I'm not putting the utility stuff in src because I don't want to risk them getting accidentally exported to prod systems.  It's only really useful for testing and dev stuff.